# Planning out Eloquent relationships in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `Project` model. Each `Project` can have a thumbnail, main image and other multiple assets / images (project details for example) and also multiple text contents (that would be placed in between these images). And each `Project` page will pull in these assets (except the thumbnail) and texts, and display them in a specific order (that I define by drag and drop on my control panel).

So basically the similar structure to what `Behance` uses for example. I'm trying to structure this using Eloquent and here is what I was thinking of doing:

I can have let's say `Asset` and `Text` models with `hasMany()` relationship on `Project` model. These two models would have a column called `pageSort` and then the controller would merge these two collections together and sort them using that `pageSort` column.

Any other suggestions?

---

EDIT:

I tried to use the polymorphic relationships in Laravel, but no success yet.

My`Project` model:

```
public function nodes()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Node::class, 'nodeable');
}
```

My `Node` model:

```
public function nodeable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Then in my code I do the following:

```
$project = new App\Project;
$project->title = 'Some title';
$project->save();

$image = new App\Image;
$image->source = 'somefile.jpg';
```

$project->nodes()->save($image);

But I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `nodeables` (`nodeable_id`, `nodeable_type`, `project_id`) values (5, App\Node, 1))'
```

So I guess it's trying to create an entry inside a pivot table `nodeables`. Then I created this table and it saved an entry inside the pivot table, but not inside `nodes` table.

This is driving me mad! :(

Answer (score 0):

I would have a `Node` model that is polymorphic, and has your `sort_order` column. A `Project` would have many `Node` models, and a `Node` could be morphed to whatever you need: `Text`, `Image`, `Video`, and so on.

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function nodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Node::class)->orderBy('sort_order');
    }
}

class Node extends Model
{
    public function nodeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('nodeable');
    }

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}

// Example
class Text extends Model
{
    public function node()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Node::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: So would `Node` have `textable`, `imageable` columns?

Comment: No. `Node` may have something like `nodeable_id` and `nodeable_type` columns. The type would be something like `Image` or `Text`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I will give this a try now.

Comment: Updated my question. Would you mind having a quick look at it, plaese?

Comment: The relation between your `Project` and `Node` models wouldn’t be a `morphedByMany`, a `Project` would just have many `Node` models, and your `Node` would be “nodeable” (as it is now), and have a foreign key pointing to the project, and your sort order column.

Comment: I followed your example and the `nodes` table is completely empty, still.. it saves an `Image` and puts `project_id` in there. But `nodes` table remains empty and therefore I cannot retrieve `nodes` using `$project->nodes()->get();`... this is so annoying :(

Comment: Your `images` table _shouldn’t_ have the `project_id` column, the `nodes` table should.

Comment: If I remove `project_id` from `images` table, it dumps out an error saying that `project_id` doesn't exist on `images` table. And `node` table has `project_id` column too. I'm using `$project->nodes()->save($image);` to save it. Maybe this is not correct?